# React-Django: How to send different functional components (React) to Django Views?

Tags: reactjs, django

So I am new to React and I can currently create different functional components when I use `npx create-react-app appname` but if I want to "package" these files and send them to my Django's view page, what is the best way to do this? I am having some trouble with webpack configuring everything in the methods I've attempted. I am trying to create a web app. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to "deploy" Django + React app, you need to use webpack on your react project, then you store react webpacked scripts in your staticfiles directory in django. Then, you define a view that returns index.html with attached scripts {% static 'reactscripts.js' %}. Thats basically all if you want to combine theese two on simple project.

I hope thats the answer you're looking for.

[edit] Also if you would like to deploy your project (after you've figured everything out), this article may help you to do so
https://mattsegal.dev/django-spa-infrastructure.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Exactly what I was looking for! Quick question for you: how did you learn about webpack and fullstack development? I'm a mechanical engineer so I am teaching myself programming, but only through projects and youtube tutorials. Any other resources that you can recommend?

Comment: Glad to help! I'm not really a fullstack developer but learning backend developer. I've started learning from basic course on Udemy (youtube is also great!). Some very great channels that I reccomend are: Dennis Ivy, JustDjango and TechWithTim. And also fun fact, the question that you've asked is exactly my problem from 3 weeks ago because I've been doing small django + react project with my friend without any react knowledge. Also, if you have any questions feel free to message me, begginings are hard. Good luck!